# compare the inputted ipaddress value with the values of multiselect box in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

**View Code:**

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Version</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   name="versions" id="versions" placeholder="Eg. 5.9.158.65" 
                   onchange='validate(this.value)'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my input field for entering ipaddress manually. **While entering the value for this field, I need to check whether the values in multiselect box(mentioned below) are lower than the entered IPaddress format.**

**Script code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var octet = '(?:25[0]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])';
    var ip = '(?:' + octet + '\\.){3}' + octet;
    var quad = '(?:\\[' + ip + '\\])|(?:' + ip + ')';
    var ipRE = new RegExp('(' + quad + ')');

    function validate(value) {
        if (ipRE.test(value)) {
            alert('"' + RegExp.$1 + '"');
        } else {
            alert('Invalid version format');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here I am validating the entered ipaddress format using regex.

**Same view code:**

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Target Versions(Supported Versions)</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="serial-lists[]" id="serial-lists" onchange='multiselect()'>
                <option value="1.0.0.8">1.0.0.8</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.2">1.0.0.2</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.3">1.0.0.3</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.4">1.0.0.4</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.5">1.0.0.5</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.6">1.0.0.6</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.7">1.0.0.7</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This field is the supported versions field which is multiselect box.

**Script code:(Code I have tried for comparing these two fields)**

```
<script>
    function multiselect() {
        var selectedValues = $('#serial-lists').text();
        var versions = document.getElementById('versions');
        if (selectedValues > versions)
            alert("not valid");
        else if (selectedValues < versions)
            alert("valid");
    }
</script>
```

But it is not working. Also I think it is not efficient too.

Comment: for more details need sample test case

Comment: it should be `document.getElementById('versions').value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for comparsion you need to convert the ip address to integer

```
function ip2int(string) {
    var parts = string.split(".");

    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var partVal = Number(parts[i]);
        sum = (sum << 8) + partVal;
    }

    return sum;
};
```

and in the validation you need the following:

```
if (ip2int(selectedValues) > ip2int(versions))
```

also the way you are retrieving the values might be invalid
if you call `$('#serial-lists').val();` it will return an array of values that are selected and you can loop through them. try to console.log the values to see what it's giving.

**EDIT**

```
function multiselect() {
        var validIPs = [];
        var inValidIPs = [];
        var selectedValues = $('#serial-lists').val(); 
        var versions = $('#versions').val();
        for(var i=0; i<selectedValues.length;i++){
            if (ip2int(selectedValues[i]) > ip2int(versions))
                inValidIPs.push(selectedValues[i]);
            else if (ip2int(selectedValues[i]) <= ip2int(versions))
                validIPs.push(selectedValues[i]);
        }
        alert("valid IPs : \n"+validIPs.join("\n")+"\nInvalid IPs : \n"+inValidIPs.join("\n"));
    }
```

From multiple selected value, you can only differ the valid and the invalid. If you want alert once, you should not call validation on change of multiple select tag, instead call on `onblur` i.e.

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="serial-lists[]" id="serial-lists" onblur='multiselect()'>
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer!! May I know what is the purpose of left shifting by 8?

Comment: ipv4 address has 4 "parts" separated by dots. each part has a value from 0-255. if you would just sum the 4 parts it would not be unique
the left shifting by 8 means that you multiply the result by 256. its basically something like the ones, tens, hundreds for the decimal numbers but on higher order

Comment: Ok, I got your point. In binary ip is formatted like `xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx`. And in your function, we just removed dot between it and get the decimal of it. Brain storming logic!

Comment: Thanks for the help SIR!!But it throws error (ie.,string.split is not a function)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
var version=$('#versions').val();
var selectedValues = $('#serial-lists').text();
  if (ip2int(selectedValues) > ip2int(versions))
    alert("not valid");
  else
    alert("valid");
}

function ip2int(string) {
    var parts = string.split(".");

    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var partVal = Number(parts[i]);
        sum = (sum << 8) + partVal;
    }

    return sum;
};
</script>

Comment: string.split might throw an error if the string you are passing is null. try to console.log, or check another browser to get a more detailed error msg

Comment: Ok SIR.May I know the value returned to the sum at first iteration in the ip2int function

Comment: Thankyou So much Sir!!.I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Try compare function like below.

```
<script>
    function multiselect() {
    var opts = $('#serial-lists')[0].options;
    var selectedValues = $.map(opts, function(elem) {
        return (elem.value || elem.text);
    });
    var versions = $('#versions').val();
    for(var i=0; i<selectedValues.length;i++){
        if (selectedValues[i] > versions)
            alert("not valid");
        else if (selectedValues < versions)
            alert("valid");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It works.But I don't want to compare it with the selected values of multiselect box.I need to compare it with all the values of multiselect box

Comment: It loops here.I don't need of looping.It needs to completely checks with the multiselect box and alerts only once.

Comment: I can not find this working at all... and it is selected!!